# rails test case error due to cookie not found during login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, cookies

For a particular rails unit test(of type PerformanceTest), I need to GET a page which requires signing in the user.

my signIn function is implemented via putting the user in the cookies object:

```
 def sign_in(user)
   cookies.permanent.signed[:saved_user] = [user.id, salt]
   current_user = user;
 end
```

but when I try to call this sign_in method in unit tests and performance tests I get an error saying object "cookies" is not found. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out how to fix this. In the unit test instead of calling

```
sign_in @test_user
```

just call

```
@controller.sign_in @test_user
```